# How to prevent combination of more than 3 characters in a loop of all permutations of a string

Tags: python

```
def toString(List): 
    return ''.join(List) 

# The main function that recursively prints all repeated permutations of the given string.

def allLexicographicRecur (string, data, last, index): 
    length = len(string) 

    for i in xrange(length): 
        data[index] = string[i] 
        if index==last: 
            print toString(data) 
        else: 
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1) 
 
def allLexicographic(string): 
    length = len(string) 
    data = [""] * (length+1) 
    string = sorted(string) 
    allLexicographicRecur(string, data, length-1, 0) 

string = "abcde"
allLexicographic(string)
```

**output**

```
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad
aaaae
aaaba
...
eeede
eeeea
eeeeb
eeeec
eeeed
eeeee
```

I want to make my loop prevent a repetition of a character more than two times in same string

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
**SKIPPED STRINGS**
aaaaa will be skipped
aaaab will be skipped
aaaac will be skipped
...
aaaba will be skipped
abeee will be skipped

**NOT SKIPPED STRINGS**
abaab will not be skipped
abada will not be skipped

etc
```

The code should skip the above strings and they should not be printed out

The main idea is to reduce computational time and increase output speed significantly

A solution where the strings are generated then filtered is highly discouraged because this will double the work instaed of reducing it

on a kind note please vote my question up if its a good one thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see no better way than to store the last generated letter, and count the number of times it has been generated in sequence.
If you generate a different one, overwrite and reset the counter.
If you are about to generate the third one, skip that letter and take the next one.